# Excel VBA compare columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two tables on the same excel sheet between rows. Following is what i am trying to achieve. I have worked something out, but it's not functionnal as it deletes rows...

```
A   B   C   D       E             F         
E1  40  12   4    4/16/2017       E4  
E2  20  1    5    6/22/2016       E2  
E1  10  0    4    6/30/2017       E1  
E1  40  12   6    4/16/2017       E4  

Should turn into :

A   B   C   D       E             F             
E1  40  12  4;6   4/16/2017       E4  
E2  20  1   5     6/22/2016       E2  
E1  10  0   4     6/30/2017       E1
```

**TASK 1**

If column A matches

If column B matches

If column C matches

If column F matches

Then

Concatenate rows on lines D and add a ";" between values
And delete rows that are concatenated.

I have achieved this with this code (just added the condition for F but it's not workind) , but it's not functional already without it, as it doesn't store values in a dictionnary probably and jumps rows, so it doesn't concatenate all of the values in the sheet and skips some too...

```
Sub TEMPLATE() 

Dim lngRow As Long For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 

If StrComp(Range("B" & lngRow), Range("B" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 And 

If StrComp(Range("A" & lngRow), Range("A" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 And 

If StrComp(Range("C" & lngRow), Range("C" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0  And 

If StrComp(Range("F" & lngRow), Range("F" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0

Then 

If Range("D" & lngRow) <> "" Then 
Range("D" & lngRow - 1) = Range("D" & lngRow - 1) & ";" & Range("D" & lngRow) 

End If 

Rows(lngRow).Delete 
End If 
Next 
End Sub
```

**TASK 2**

Since this is an update file, I would like to compare every rows on the old file and make changes, and highloght them, if possible. Let's say, if my E1 line up there has been added a value on B, it would highlight B case and add the value.

I don't know how to do this one, I believe it should loop between the old sheet and the updated sheet where I run the previous macro.

Thanks guys for your help !

Comment: Welcome! Could you clarify your desired output a bit? In your example column F doesn't match. Also what happens to values in column C and D? You mention that you want concatenation in column B yet your code changes column D. Also add an "and" to the if statements to make it clear that all of them should apply at once.

Comment: Hi, thanks ! Just edited the code, sorry and added some details on the output. Basically it's just a match of cilumns A, B, C and F, and concatenation on column F.

Comment: Can the data be sorted first ?

Comment: It looks like you are matching on column E also. If not, which date would you want to pick?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not putting a condition on that, it's not necessary if the other columns match, columns E would match too.

Comment: Yeah, it can, maybe it'll ease things. I didn't sort it before, so I don't know if it's relevant for me.

Comment: You mention that you want to compare 2 tables are in the same sheet. However, both your example and code seem to be working with a single table, namely columns A to F. Is it correct in assuming that what you are trying to do is checking a *single* table for duplicates (in a specific way and removing them in a specific way)? Or are there 2 tables?

Comment: I meant for task two, i need to compare two tables on different sheets. But for the main task, I'm not doing that. I'm checking for duplicates and concatening them, and removing them once concatenated. I didn't manage to get a code for task 2

Answer (score 0):

The code below should complete your TASK 1. It assumes everything is in the first sheet. It works with your example, but I haven't tested it much further so beware. However, I think it's clear enough so you can edit it if needed.

TASK 1:

```
Sub filter_data()
    
    'Initialize iterator at row 1
    i = 0
    
    'Loop through data until no more rows
    Do While Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value2 <> ""
        
        'Get values of row
        A_val_1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value2
        B_val_1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(i, 1).Value2
        C_val_1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(i, 2).Value2
        D_val_1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(i, 3).Value2
        F_val_1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(i, 5).Value2
        
        'Loop through data again to check if duplicates
        j = i 'Initialize iterator at row i
        Do While Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(j, 0).Value2 <> ""
            
            If j <> i Then 'Skip selected row
            
                'Get values of row
                A_val_2 = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(j, 0).Value2
                B_val_2 = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(j, 1).Value2
                C_val_2 = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(j, 2).Value2
                D_val_2 = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(j, 3).Value2
                F_val_2 = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(j, 5).Value2
                
                'If conditions satisfied
                If A_val_1 = A_val_2 And B_val_1 = B_val_2 And C_val_1 = C_val_2 And F_val_1 = F_val_2 Then
                    
                    'Concatenate on D
                    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(i, 3).Value2 = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(i, 3).Value2 & ";" & D_val_2
                    
                    'Delete duplicate row
                    Sheets(1).Rows(j + 1).Delete
                    
                    'Decrement incrementor by 1 to make up for deleted row
                    j = j - 1

                End If
            End If
            
        j = j + 1 'increment
        Loop
        
    i = i + 1 'increment
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Maybe (?) I'll get back to TASK 2 later, but that should be very straightforward - you just need to loop through all cells, compare an highlight.

EDIT: Task 2 below as far as I understood it. It only checks for difference in the new sheet, highlights differences from old sheet cell-wise and appends the old value to the LEFT of the new value (can be changed). Again, it works with your example.

TASK 2:

```
Sub compare_data()

    'Initialize sheets to compare; only cells on new sheet will be highlighted
    old_sheet_idx = 1 'index of old sheet
    new_sheet_idx = 2 'index of updated sheet
    
    'Get number of populated rows & column in new sheet
    new_sheet_rows = Range(Sheets(new_sheet_idx).Range("A1"), Sheets(new_sheet_idx).Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count
    new_sheet_cols = Range(Sheets(new_sheet_idx).Range("A1"), Sheets(new_sheet_idx).Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Count
    
    'Clear all formats in new sheet
    Sheets(new_sheet_idx).Cells.ClearFormats
    
    'Loop through all rows of new sheet
    For i = 1 To new_sheet_rows
    
        'Loop through all cells of the row
        For j = 1 To new_sheet_cols
        
            'Get cell value
            new_cell = Sheets(new_sheet_idx).Range("A" & i).Offset(0, j - 1).Value2
            old_cell = Sheets(old_sheet_idx).Range("A" & i).Offset(0, j - 1).Value2
            
            'Compare
            If new_cell <> old_cell Then
                Sheets(new_sheet_idx).Range("A" & i).Offset(0, j - 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'highlight yellow
                Sheets(new_sheet_idx).Range("A" & i).Offset(0, j - 1).Value2 = old_cell & ";" & new_cell 'concatenate old value;new value
            End If
            
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I think that's what I've been missing : 'Decrement incrementor by 1 to make up for deleted row because on my code, it deletes and then skip rows because it does n-1 instead of n. I'll try your code, thank you so much

Comment: @Sara, yes and also your code seems to only be comparing 2 rows at a time, i.e. the current row with the previous one.